# LAST_INSERT_ID Mysql is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have the follow query

```
INSERT
INTO
    profile(
        fullname,
        email,
        cpfcnpj,
        identity,
        phone,
        cellphoneone,
        cellphonetwo,
        birthday,
        cep,
        address,
    )
VALUES(
    : fullname, : email, : cpfcnpj, : identity, : phone, : cellphoneone, : cellphonetwo, : birthday, : cep, : address
);
SELECT
    LAST_INSERT_ID() AS lid;
```

PHP Code

```
$insertProfile = $database->driver()->prepare("
INSERT INTO wordprofile (fullname, email, cpfcnpj, identity, phone, cellphoneone, cellphonetwo, birthday, cep, address, city, state, reference, number, pay, contract) VALUES (:fullname, :email, :cpfcnpj, :identity, :phone, :cellphoneone, :cellphonetwo, :birthday, :cep, :address, :city, :state, :reference, :number, :pay, :contract); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() as lid;"
);

$insertProfile->bindValue(":fullname", $arg["name"]." ". $arg["lastname"]);
$insertProfile->bindValue(":email", $arg["email"]);
$insertProfile->bindValue(":cpfcnpj", $arg["cpfcnpj"]);
$insertProfile->bindValue(":identity", $arg["rg"]);
$insertProfile->bindValue(":phone", $tel);
$insertProfile->bindValue(":cellphoneone", $arg["cel1"]);
$insertProfile->bindValue(":cellphonetwo", $cel2);
$insertProfile->bindValue(":birthday", $birthday);
$insertProfile->bindValue(":cep", $arg["zip"]);
$insertProfile->bindValue(":address", $arg["address"]);

$insertProfile->execute();
$lastid = $insertProfile->fetch()[0];
echo $lastid; //nothing, if change to var_dump returns false
```

It works properly when i run into phpmyadmin or mysql prompt. However that same query returns false in PHP; that insert works, only `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS lid;` does not returns.

Comment: please write your code !!

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: $lastId = $insertProfile->lastInsertId(); http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: @FrédéricClausset does not working. `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::lastInsertId()`

Comment: $database->driver()->lasInsertId(). lasInsertId is a method of the PDO driver not the statement. My mistake.

Comment: please check this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: I've read a lot of tutorials, including php.net.

Comment: Most database libraries I have worked with only allow a single query per execute. Your INSERT and SELECT are separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work actually because [PDO doesn't support several queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) executed in one statement.
You have to make another execute with a separated query or use the method [`lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php) as mentioned in the comments by Frederic.